# Modify the visual cues - show position of mouse when control key is pressed

Tags: mouse, 20.10, mouse-pointer

I have turned on the option "Show position of the mouse pointer when the control key is pressed" in Ubuntu 20.1, and it works. The visual cue, however, is very faint and more times than not, it is not helpful in finding the mouse pointer and I end up having to find it as I would without this option turned on.
Is there an option to change the way the mouse pointer's position is shown? The visual cue used in Windows is much better and easier to see, for example.

Comment: Similar question here remained unanswered: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1397123/modify-the-visual-cues-show-position-of-mouse-when-control-key-is-pressed. Be aware that Ubuntu 20.10 is EOL and not anymore supported here. So your question is off topic.

Comment: There are gnome-shell extensions that will do that. You might look at this one... https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3438/jiggle/

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format; so if you're using 20.1 you're using a *fake* as no releases occurred in 2020-January. If using 21.04 your intended upgrade was to [21.04; however that's now gone as it's EOL too](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/) as you've missed the 9 month window.